# How to properly deal with global states in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Let’s say I am creating a bookstore and I want to add, delete, update, etc, books to my list (basically, manipulate the books list).
I am creating a global state with the context API and functions like below:

```
//defining my global state
const [books, setBooks] = useState([ ])

// defining a function to manipulate the global state
  const addBook = (newBook) => {
    let newBooksList = [newBook, …books]
    setBooks(newBooksList)
  }
```

And then I pass those functions to the components that needed it.
Is this the right approach? I mean, I know that it works but is this considered good practice or there are other better ways to do those types of things?
I not sure if it is a good functional approach or if I should do it in a more oop approach, I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using is fine if you want to manage the state with Context.

About the OOP approach, of course, the way you use there is just a preference, but you don't see many examples using OOP in the React world. So, if you are seeking an exact answer to that, just stick to the method you are using there.

Optionally, you can use a custom hook for your Context. You can find an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/authentication-with-react-context-d3x0r). It is just for the auth state but the logic is the same.

One final note, though you are using Context there and it seems fine, do not forget that Context is not a state manager. There are disadvantages to using it as a state manager, like all the components (wrapped by this Context) rerender when something changes in the state, either this change is related to them or not.